# JQ: Filter json array as per stedolan JQ library

Tags: json, filter, jq

I am quite new with JQ library.
This is the incoming response:

```
{"message":"Details fetched successfully","status":1,"details":[{"test":"a","amount":2500.0,"pre":["11","429393","543216","987657"]},{"test":"b","amount":1500.0,"pre":["480855"]},{"test":"c","amount":0.0,"pre":["No data present"]},{"test":"d","amount":1500.0,"pre":["526702"]},{"test":"e","amount":2500.0,"pre":["No data present"]}]}
```

Output required after applying JQ filter:

```
  {
  "msg": "Details fetched successfully",
  "status": 1,
  "details": {
      "a": {
        "amount": 2500,
        "pre": [
          "11",
          "429393",
          "543216",
          "987657"
        ]
      },
      "b": {
        "amount": 1500,
        "pre": [
          "480855"
        ]
      },
      "c": {
        "amount": 0,
        "pre": [
          "No data present"
        ]
      },
      "d": {
        "amount": 1500,
        "pre": [
          "526702"
        ]
      },
      "e": {
        "amount": 2500,
        "pre": [
          "No data present"
        ]
      }
  }
}
```

I tried using the below JQ filter but I am getting "details" as array but "details" is object in final output.

JQ filter:

```
{msg: .message, status: .status, details: [.details[]| { (.test) : {amount: .amount, pre: .pre }}]}
```

Comment: Welcome. Rather than make us work out what transformation you're trying to achieve, by comparing the input and the output JSON, it would be better if you described it in your question too. Please do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INDEX` can turn an array into an object with keys based on a sub-expression:

```bash
jq '.details |= INDEX(.test)'
```

```json
{
  "message": "Details fetched successfully",
  "status": 1,
  "details": {
    "a": {
      "test": "a",
      "amount": 2500,
      "pre": [
        "11",
        "429393",
        "543216",
        "987657"
      ]
    },
    "b": {
      "test": "b",
      "amount": 1500,
      "pre": [
        "480855"
      ]
    },
    "c": {
      "test": "c",
      "amount": 0,
      "pre": [
        "No data present"
      ]
    },
    "d": {
      "test": "d",
      "amount": 1500,
      "pre": [
        "526702"
      ]
    },
    "e": {
      "test": "e",
      "amount": 2500,
      "pre": [
        "No data present"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7EGDaDll9Rd)

---

To delete the `test` field from the result, use `map_values` with `del` on the resulting object:

```bash
jq '.details |= (INDEX(.test) | map_values(del(.test)))'
```

```json
{
  "message": "Details fetched successfully",
  "status": 1,
  "details": {
    "a": {
      "amount": 2500,
      "pre": [
        "11",
        "429393",
        "543216",
        "987657"
      ]
    },
    "b": {
      "amount": 1500,
      "pre": [
        "480855"
      ]
    },
    "c": {
      "amount": 0,
      "pre": [
        "No data present"
      ]
    },
    "d": {
      "amount": 1500,
      "pre": [
        "526702"
      ]
    },
    "e": {
      "amount": 2500,
      "pre": [
        "No data present"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4m63UTA448a)

Comment: I just found another way to implement above transformation.
{msg: .message, status: .status, details: .details | map({ (.test) : {amount: .amount, pre: .pre }}) | add }

Comment: Which way is better in terms of performance as per your understanding?

Comment: @ShivamChetani On the sample data they are pretty much the same. Yet, tiny differences may grow significant with more data involved. And the extent depends on the actual structure. For instance, if the array items in the big data set have a lot of fields but you only want to keep two of them, your build-up approach would be more efficient than the reductive approch using `del`. Vice versa if you want to keep many and drop only few. On the other hand, if the array itself gets big, using `reduce` (in the implementation of  `INDEX`) may be more memory-friendly than `map`.